# How to I add 'File-> Open Folder' to the Sublime Text 2 menu?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to diff two files with Sublime Text 2.  Some answers I've seen on this forum recommend using the 'File->Open Folder' menu option, but it's not appearing on my File-> menu. Not even greyed out, just not there.  I have looked into Preferences->Default Settings and there does not seem to be an open folder command option that I can add to my User Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use Sublime Text 3? It's stable now.

Btw, you just have to do : `File > Open...` or `CMD + o`and select your folder.

Comment: It just wasn't obvious!  I see now, if the two files are in the same folder, and you do File->Open on the folder, the left sidebar appears.  You can then select two files and right click to see the 'Diff Files' option.